# Convert date & time in Excel, to time only, and round to nearest 30 minutes

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to convert excel date & time to time only and nearest 30 minutes. Example 1/5/2017 4:38:29 PM convert to 1630

```
          A1                    B1
 1/5/2017  4:38:29 PM          1630
 1/5/2017  5:03:40 PM          1700
 1/5/2017  4:39:27 PM          1630
```

I tried if function & vlookup  with

```
=MROUND((TEXT(A1,"hhmm")),1/48)
```

but I get 0:00 answer, and also

```
=MOD(Y5,"0:30")
```

but I get a 0 answer.

Comment: How do you MROUND `5:03:40` to `1630`?

Comment: I have a pending edit to correct that given Cathy seems to have not come back to fix. (At some risk of misinterpretation of Cathy's orig intent.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you were almost there. You need MOD to get the decimal portion of a datetime (i.e. the time) then MROUND to the nearest half-hour.

```
=MROUND(MOD(A1, 1),TIME(0,30,0))
```

[image]

FLOOR and CEILING operate the same as MROUND in case you require the lower or higher half-hour.

You may need to format the cell for the desired time format mask.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data starts in A1, copy the following down to suit:

```
=HOUR(A1)&IF(MINUTE(A1)>29,30,"00")
```